# Excel - Visual Basic - Sorting through data on sheet table from data on another sheet table

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with visual basic and ended up copying code from another problem that was similar to what I am trying but it ended up not working properly. Since I'm new at VB it is something I'm not able to figure out. I have 2 tables that look the exact same 1 just has more information on it. What I want to do is take the information from the table with the extra information, the columns from call date and after should be filled out. What I want to do is use the Lead ID from those that have been filled out on the sheet called updated, check them against the raw data sheet. If the data from the updated sheet lead ID matches the one from the Raw Data sheet I want the data from the Raw data sheet to be deleted in that row.  I updaed the code but now I'm getting a whole new error. I keep erroring out on Subscript Out of Range (Error 9) on the                     dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").ListRows(mm).Delete

[Raw Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkH21.png)

Here is the code I found and was using

```
   Sub SheetUpdateTool()
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet, updateSheet As Worksheet
    Dim valueSearch As Integer
    Dim tt As Integer, mm As Integer
    Dim dataTable As ListObject, updateTable As ListObject
    
    
    Set dataSheet = Worksheets("Raw Data")
    Set updateSheet = Worksheets("Updated")
    'x = dataSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
    'MsgBox (x)
    'lastRowLookUp = dataSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row
    'updateLastRow = updateSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(x1Up).Row
    'dataTable = dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data")
    'updateTable = updateSheet.ListObjects("Updated_Data")
    
    For tt = 1 To updateSheet.ListObjects("Updated_Data").Range.Rows.Count
        valueToSearch = updateSheet.ListObjects("Updated_Data").DataBodyRange(tt, "A").Value
        For mm = 1 To dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").Range.Rows.Count
            If dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").DataBodyRange(mm, "A").Value = valueToSearch Then
                dataSheet.ListObjects("Raw_Data").ListRows(mm).Delete
                'MsgBox ("Deleted")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next mm
    Next tt
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a table named 'Raw_Data' on the sheet 'Raw Data'?

Comment: The table is named Raw_Data on the Raw Data sheet and on the Updated Sheet the table is Updated_Data

Comment: So I got it to go through the loop. For some reason when it gets into the If Statement it breaks. I had it do some message boxes but it doesn't show anything in there.